# How to get post information

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

How I can get informations from post ID of any page?

I try to get it with php sdk graph but I fuiled every times.

that what I want :
Just put ID of post from any page to get informations (page, img, quote, created date, ... ).

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Facebook app needs the [Page Public Content Access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature/#reference-PAGES_ACCESS) Feature. Then your can fetch post information from any page, but depending on your use case it may be hard to get a positive review.